# Nested Promise execution is out of sync

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

I have a simple setup, illustrated in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqLhsu1t/3/):

```
var doDelay = function(who) {
    return Promise.delay(50)
        .tap(function() {
            console.log(who + ' done');
        });
};

Promise.resolve()
    .then(doDelay('a'))
    .tap(function() {
        console.log('a done2');
    })
    .then(doDelay('b'))
    .tap(function() {
        console.log('b done2');
    })
    .then(function() {
        console.log('all done!');
    });
```

The output is:

```
a done2
b done2
all done!
a done
b done
```

But I expect:

```
a done
b done
a done2
b done2
all done!
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bergi points out, it's not valid to pass a promise as the argument to `then`, but even if it were allowed, another issue is that as soon as you call `delayMany('a')`, the `Promise.delay(50)` inside it will start executing which is not what you are looking to do.

You can either wrap the call in an anonymous function, or use `.bind()`:

```
var delayMany = function(who) {
    return Promise.delay(50)
    .tap(function() {
        console.log(who  + ' done');
    });
};

Promise.resolve()
.then(delayMany.bind(null, 'a'))
.tap(function() { console.log('a done2'); })

.then(delayMany.bind(null, 'b'))
.tap(function() { console.log('b done2'); })

.then(function() {
    console.log('all done!');
});
```

Q: "Why doesn't `then` throw an error when I pass a promise to it?"

The answer to this is in the [Promises/A+ spec](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-24):

> A promise’s `then` method accepts two arguments:
>
> `promise.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)`
>
> 2.2.1. Both `onFulfilled` and `onRejected` are optional arguments:
>
> 2.2.1.1. **If `onFulfilled` is not a function, it must be ignored.**

Comment: Why doesn't `then` throw an error when I pass a promise to it?

Comment: I remember seeing that! But why would they not spec it to throw an error?

Comment: @Domi I wouldn't know, but `then` has to be able to accept non-functions so that you can do `.then(null, function (failure) {})`. I can only assume that for simplicity's sake, they made it so that all non-functions are just ignored.

Comment: You think it's a good idea to patch the `then` function to give at least a warning if one of the arguments does not evaluate to `false` and is not a function? I am afraid, me and other promise-newbies working on this code will repeat this error...

Comment: @Domi I don't think it's a good idea to patch `then`, because (a) it violates the spec, and (b) it could easily cause unexpected results. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903781/wrapping-jquery-ajax-behind-a-facade-in-q-js-without-refactoring/27909906)'s someone who tried to patch `then` to enable some spec-violating behavior, and it didn't go well.

Comment: I reckon! I guess the question of whether to patch or not underlies the ultimate StackOverflow question anyway: How to prevent stupid and obvious programmer errors! Admittedly, this sort of question or discussion does not belong here though... I'll see what I can do :/

Comment: @Domi, you could do a "debug-only" patch for `.then()` that was designed to notify you when you did something wrong during initial development and testing of your code, but not designed to be in place when the code was final tested or deployed.  From my C/C++ days, I'd think of it like an `ASSERT()`.

Answer (score 2):

You must not pass a promise (the result of immediately *calling* `delayMany`) to `then`. Instead, it expects a callback *function* to execute when the context promise resolves. You'll need to wrap your `delayMany` invocation in a function expression:

```
Promise.resolve()
.then(function(undefined) { return delayMany(xsa); })
.tap(function(xsa) { console.log(xsa[0] + ' done2'); })
.then(function(xsa) { return delayMany(xsb) })
.tap(function(xsb) { console.log(xsb[0] + ' done2'); })
.then(function(xsb) { console.log('all done!'); });
```

Comment: Me stupid... Of course I am actually running the function before the Promise library even gets a chance to defer it! Thanks!

Comment: Why `function(undefined)`?

Comment: @thefourtheye: Because that's what the `Promise.resolve()` promise resolves with, and what gets passed to the callback :-) Of course the parameters are not used here anywhere, but I always like to emphasize that the promise callbacks are made for *getting a resolution value*…

Comment: @Bergi I simplified and changed names in my code, just FYI :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using bluebird you can simply use the `.delay` method instead:

```
Promise.resolve()
    .delay('a', 50)
    .tap(function() {
        console.log('a done2');
    })
    .delay('b', 50)
    .tap(function() {
        console.log('b done2');
    })
    .then(function() {
        console.log('all done!');
    });
```

Comment: The question was in regard to nested promise execution. The problem was me calling `then` on non-functions :)